# How to upload file to product on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, backend, file-upload, upload

I am developing a Magento 2.2.x e-commerce which requires some of the catalog's products to have an associated PDF (or any other file extensions).
At the start, I thought that it was possible to do using the product attribute but there is no File upload field available.

How can I associate uploaded files to a product? Is there any good extension or a good tutorial to try to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for readymade modules you may use one of them. its free of cost

https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-productAttachment
https://marketplace.magento.com/prince-module-productattachment.html

Comment: That's a good extension but I just need to add a file input to product form in the backend and save it accordingly.